# Traversing an array created using useRef in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following in a react native application:

```
export default function MyScreen() {

  const componentRefs = useRef([]);

  return (
            <View >
              {myArray.map(
                (wc, index) =>
                  (
                    <MyObject
                      key={index}
                      ref={el => componentRefs.current[index] = el}
                      index={index}
                      // other props
                    />
                  )
              )}
            </View>
  );
}
```

Each `MyObject` instance displays a word. I want to add functionality which will, when a button is pressed, highlight each word in turn, and play an audio file with its pronunciation.

In order to do this, I need to store reference to each `MyObject` instance in the parent `MyScreen` function, so I can subsequently traverse through all the displayed words.

My initial stab at this is to use `useRef` to create an array to store the references, as illustrated above.

As an initial test, I have a button handler to check if the references have been saved. This simply loops through each item in `componentRefs`:

```
componentRefs.current.forEach((x) => console.log(x));
```

However, nothing is displayed.
There is also a warning:

```
Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

What is the best way to store the references in the parent to enable the desired functionality?

Thanks very much

Comment: `componentRefs.current.forEach` but why do you need that? You are using ref incorrectly

Comment: Accessing child components from the parent is generally an anti-pattern. You can most likely pass down callbacks and/or IDs, or use a context for access to shared state.

Comment: @Konrad can you explain?

Comment: componentRefs.current.forEach((x) => console.log(x)); does not display anything to the console

Comment: You should pass the log function as prop to each children, and they will take care of the calling

Comment: @user1052610 It's not logging anything cause the array is empty. You never put anything in it. `componentRefs[index] =` <-- see... ? I'd also like to reiterate that this is a complete antipattern and "solving this" will only create more issues for you since you are trying to force something to behave the way you want instead of learning how to actually use it.

Comment: Thanks. What is the correct way to do this? If you could show this in an answer it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Like I already stated: pass down a callback and/or ID, or use a context for shared state. I can't make a more concrete answer then that since you've omitted all details except the fact that you want to put things in an array from useRef. In general you don't want to access children from the parent. You want to only pass things down the hierarchy. I have no clue what your use case is here.

Comment: Have a read about what an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) is.

Comment: Thanks - will edit question to explain better

Comment: You should not edit styles using ref. You should create a state and change the state

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try with below Code:

```
export default function App() {
  const componentRefs = useRef([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Object.keys(componentRefs).map((item, i) => console.log(componentRefs[item]))
  }, [componentRefs]);
  return (
    <View>
      {myArray.map(
        (wc, index) =>
          (componentRefs[index] = (
            <MyObject
              key={index}
              index={index}
              // other props
            />
          ))
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: There is no error, when using componentRefs.current.forEach,  but nothing is displayed. Logging a specific element prints 'undefined'.

Comment: can you describe whats inside MyObject

Comment: also receive Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Comment: @user1052610 I have edited answer please review it

Comment: This logs correctly once (in useEffect), but not in the button handler using bcomponentRefs.current.forEach((x) => console.log(x));

Comment: Have accepted this answer, thanks very much. One issue remaining is how to clear the componentRefs array. componentRefs.current=[] and componentRefs.current.length=0 do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code example to use `useRef` inside loop. This is just an example, change components according to you.

```
export default function MyScreen() {
  const componentRefs = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    componentRefs.current.forEach(el => console.log(el));
  }, [componentRefs]);

  return (
    <div>
      {myArray.map(
        (wc, index) => (
          <MyObject
            key={index}
            index={index}
            componentRefs={componentRefs}
            // other props
          />
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const MyObject = ({ index, componentRefs }) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  componentRefs.current[index] = ref;
  return (
    <View ref={ref}>
      children
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: @user1052610 I have edited the answer again. Now it should give you all the elements inside componentRefs.current.